# NLTK context-free grammars

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, context-free-grammar

I am just wondering how would you add an optional grammer in the rule

```
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.app.rdparser()
```

For example, the normal way to add a optional grammer is by putting it in parentheses: NP -> NP (PP)

But in the program how would you do it? parentheses doesnt  work.

```
S   Þ NP VP
NP  Þ NP PP | Det N
VP  Þ V NP PP
PP  Þ P NP

Det Þ 'the' | 'a'
N   Þ 'man' | 'park' | 'dog' | 'boy' | 'girl'
V   Þ 'was' | 'saw' 
P   Þ 'in' | 'under' | 'with'
```

Thanks,

Ray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NP -> NP | NP PP
```

But note that, with this rule, you can stack `NP` nodes indefinitely in the parse tree.