# NLTK: filter sentences with specific structures

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

How to filter sentences with specific structures using NLTK?
For example, we have the following definition of a context free grammar:

```
  1. S → NP VP
  2. S → Aux NP VP
  3. S → VP
  4. NP → Pronoun
  5. NP → Proper-Noun
  6. NP → Det Nominal
  7. Nominal → Noun
  8. Nominal → Nominal Noun
  9. Nominal → Nominal PP
  10.VP → Verb
  11.VP → Verb NP
  12.VP → VP PP
  13.PP → Prep NP
```

As can be seen, three types of sentence structures are defined:

```
  1. S → NP VP
  2. S → Aux NP VP
  3. S → VP
```

Given the following sentence, I want to know if this sentence conforms to any of the above three sentence structures.

> I am not much for country music but it has the potential for beauty, with its combined inclusions of comedy and sadness.

My question is, how should I do it using NLTK?

Answer (score 2):

http://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html

Should explain everything you need for this. Basically you have to first tokenize the sentence (break it up into individual tokens) and then they are tagged with the corresponding PoS that nltk identifies them as.

This returns a list of tuples, and then there are any number of ways to compare those tuples to the ones in your grammar.

Specific code to guard against faulty future links:

```
>>> text = word_tokenize("And now for something completely different")
>>> nltk.pos_tag(text)
[('And', 'CC'), ('now', 'RB'), ('for', 'IN'), ('something', 'NN'),
('completely', 'RB'), ('different', 'JJ')]
```

Comment: In this [link](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch08.html), in Example 8.12 (code_sentential_complement.py), it uses a simple filter to find verbs that take sentential complements. Can we use a similar code to first parse the sentence into a syntactic tree, then filter the syntactic tree? According to the solution in your answer, we have to first find out the POS tags of the words in the sentences, which seems unnecessary.

Comment: I mean, it's a little roundabout, but nltk has pos tagging. There is an implicit syntactic tree in the pos tagging that nltk does. By finding the pos tags you are in fact finding that tree. There's a little extra work involved, but nltk isn't actually made for dealing with context-free grammars, it's made for straight nlp, like pos tagging.

Comment: I understand what you mean. Thanks for your help. It seems that I will need automaton to perform the matching between POS tags and the CFG.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8591562/nltk-context-free-grammars?rq=1

Might be of some help

Comment: I think this is an example of bad answer (with all respect) Since the link shows 404 error and therefor it is not useful anymore.

Comment: @MostafaAhangarha Thanks for the catch. Updated the link. Issue with 4 year old answers.